# Enterprise Wide GPO Audit

Tags: windows, active-directory

How can I generate a report of users who are exempt from a specific GPO?

HR is asking me for a report of users who are exempt from an inactivity lockout group policy.  Is there a way to run an automated report or is this something I'll need to do manually?  We have over 500 end-points across three sites, so I really wouldn't want to run around to each system in the company to get this data?

Thanx...

Answer (score 3):

This should be fairly easy by determining the scope of management of the GPO.

1. Are these computer or user settings?
2. Where is the GPO linked? What objects exist in the location where the GPO is linked?
3. What is the Security Filtering for the GPO?

Example 1: If these are computer settings, and the GPO is linked to the domain root, and the Security Filtering is set to Authenticated Users... then the GPO will apply to all computers in the domain.

Example 2: If these are user settings, and the GPO is linked to a specific OU, and the Security Filtering is set to a specific security group... then the GPO will apply to all users in the OU who are members of the security group.